# Loading gstreamer plugins in static executable

Tags: static-libraries, gstreamer

I need to build a static Linux executable with gstreamer and use the queue factory which is part of the coreelements plugin. What I did was:

- Configured gstreamer (version 1.12.4) with: `./configure --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-static-plugins`
- Built it and gst-plugin-base
- Added in my code:
  `GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
  GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(coreelements);`
- Linked my app with libgstcoreelements.a (together with gstreamer-1.0, gstbase-1.0 and gstapp-1.0)

Linking fails with: 
`undefined reference to gst_plugin_coreelements_register()`

I can verify that `gst_plugin_coreelements_register` is in the static library file:

`$ nm libgstcoreelements.a |grep gst_plugin_coreelements_register
00000000000002c0 T gst_plugin_coreelements_register`

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was missing is an `extern "C" { }` block around the first gstreamer macro as it declares an extern C-style function, and my application is compiled with g++:

```
extern "C" {
GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_DECLARE(coreelements);
}
```

Comment: I compile pure c code and link with `gcc`/`ld` and still have the same problem. `nm main.o | grep coreelements` shows `U gst_plugin_coreelements_register` and `nm libgstcoreelements.a | grep coreelements` shows `0000000000000100 T gst_plugin_coreelements_register`. How don't they meld with each other?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't actually link to `libgstcoreelements.a` which resides in `lib/gstreamer-1.0` (not `lib`).